# React .map function not working after Django backend GET with axios

Tags: reactjs, django

I am trying to make a simple React frontend while using Django Rest Framework as a backend. When I make the call to Django and then try to use the .map function to display the data, I get an "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function". I am a React noob so it is definitely something I am doing.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
      users: []
    }
  
  
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/')
    .then(res => {
      const users = res.data;
      this.setState({ users });
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        { this.state.users.map(user => <li>{user.username}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the data you're getting from the response from API?

Comment: Oh. Actually it doesn't look like I am getting any data. I can see the data on the Django side, but if I log the axios request, I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
 componentDidMount() {
    let data = null;
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/')
    .then(res => {
      const users = res.data;
      data = users
    })
    this.setState({ data });
  }
```

Also make sure to put your api address in an .env file, more on that here:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

NOTE: I work in function components so I'm new at class components